# Wrong detection of CPU instruction during DPDK build?

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build DPDK using the following command:
I have to use the Dcpu_instruction_set due to different server models.

```
meson -Dcpu_instruction_set=cascadelake -Dprefix=/ build
```

However, in some of the VMs, we are seeing AVX512 is selected even though the VM does not have them.
If I do not use the parameter Dcpu_instruction_set, it's working as expected.

Currently, my application crashes if I build with this parameter.

Any ideas why dpdk build is detecting AVX512 flags?

DPDK ver : 21.11

```
Checking if "AVX512 checking" compiles: YES
Fetching value of define "__SSE4_2__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AES__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX2__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX512BW__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX512CD__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX512DQ__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX512F__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__AVX512VL__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__PCLMUL__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__RDRND__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__RDSEED__" : 1
Fetching value of define "__VPCLMULQDQ__" :


cpuid | grep AVX512
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false
      AVX512F: AVX-512 foundation instructions = false
      AVX512DQ: double & quadword instructions = false
      AVX512IFMA: fused multiply add           = false
      AVX512PF: prefetch instructions          = false
      AVX512ER: exponent & reciprocal instrs   = false
      AVX512CD: conflict detection instrs      = false
      AVX512BW: byte & word instructions       = false
      AVX512VL: vector length                  = false
      AVX512VBMI: vector byte manipulation     = false
      AVX512_VBMI2: byte VPCOMPRESS, VPEXPAND  = false
      AVX512_VNNI: neural network instructions = false
      AVX512_BITALG: bit count/shiffle         = false
      AVX512: VPOPCNTDQ instruction            = false
      AVX512_4VNNIW: neural network instrs     = false
      AVX512_4FMAPS: multiply acc single prec  = false
      AVX512_VP2INTERSECT: intersect mask regs = false

Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              12
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           6
NUMA node(s):        6
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
BIOS Vendor ID:      GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               45
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8253 CPU @ 2.20GHz
BIOS Model name:     Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8253 CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             2194.843
BogoMIPS:            4389.68
Hypervisor vendor:   VMware
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            22528K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   2,3
NUMA node2 CPU(s):   4,5
NUMA node3 CPU(s):   6,7
NUMA node4 CPU(s):   8,9
NUMA node5 CPU(s):   10,11
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx hypervisor lahf_lm pti arat
```

Answer (score 0):

Question: Any idea why the dpdk build is detecting AVX512 flags?

Answer: here is the fundamental problem, you are forcing the meson to build the binary for `cpu_instruction_set=cascadelake`. Cascade lake has AVX512 SIMD Execution engines, hence the compiler (GCC) builds and optimizes with AVX512 code path.

Confusing Information: in some of the VMs, we see AVX512 is selected even though the VM does not have them.

Answer: VM generated with virtual box, Xen, or QEMu inherits the host ISA (instruction set) by default. Unless one precisely tunes or selects the processor type. Hence any Binary or application which is built with the most common ISA (like SSE or AVX2) generic compliance to all platforms can not be expected.

Solution:

1. do not compile for the specific platform, if the VM that gets deployed is not sure whether to use the ISA.
2. or update the application to use `rte_cpu_is_supported` function which will determine compile time flag (avx512f via cascade-lake instruction) is available in VM

Note: Please check the [DPDK Link](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html) for `-Dplatform=native`

Comment: We are moving away from -Dplatform=native as it had caused issues between 2 server model 740 &750... i.e build on 750  and run on 740

Comment: not even clear what you are trying to say, may this some dell server model?